# Call Java methods in Javascript using React

Tags: javascript, java, reactjs

I am trying to make a webpage that displays the price of assets from different exchanges.  I have a java class that makes the http requests and now I need to somehow call those variables with my js code that is designing my webpage.  Any help would be amazing, and please let me know if there is anything else that should be added code-wise to help determine my issue?

I figure the calls go around here, but I am unsure if I need to also do anything in my java class, like save the variables in certain formats as right now they are in maps.

```
<div className = 'Middle'>
       <Exchange name = "Coinbase" btcBuy = "" btcSell = "" ethBuy = "" ethSell = ""/>
       <Exchange name = "Binance" btcBuy = "" btcSell = "" ethBuy = "" ethSell = ""/>
       <Recommendations/>
    </div>
```

Comment: You don't want to do that. You want to make some HTTP request to a web server written in Java.

Comment: Do you mean you have a Java backend with an endpoint that your React code needs to call?

Comment: @Andy that is correct. I have a java backend that does the http requests, I just cannot figure out to get those values into the js frontend.  Also by endpoint, does that mean I can only call a single variable with a js call as right now I have three hashmaps consisting of 12 variables whose values I need on the webpage.

Comment: Look up how to use `fetch` or `axios` with react.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of issues. The first is [how you deal with state](https://reactjs.org/docs/getting-started.html) - once you've got your data how can your component render it. The second is how do you call an endpoint lots of times, but still update the state with just one collection of data.

First: React functional components [can use hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html), and in this example we're using both `useState` to store the data, and `useEffect` to get the data.

Second: build an array of promises (where each element in the array is a new `fetch` to the server), and then use [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) to wait for all of the server calls to resolve. You can then update the state with the data, and then use that state to render the component, and its child components.

The code will look vaguely like this.

```
const { useEffect, useState } = React;

function Example() {

  const [ data, setData ] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {

    // Generic fetch params
    const arr = [1, 2, 3];

    async getData() {

      // Get an array of fetch promises using the params
      // Wait for them to resolve, return the parsed data, and
      // then set the state with that data
      const promises = arr.map(el => fetch(`endpoint?query${el}`));
      const response = await Promise.all(promises);
      const data = response.map(async el => await el.json());
      setData(data);
    }
    getData();
  }, []);

  // `map` over the data to create your
  // Exchange components
  return (
    <div>
      {data.map(obj => {
        <Exchange
          name={obj.name}
          btcBuy=""
          btcSell=""
          ethBuy=""
          ethSell=""
        />
      })}
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(
  <Example />,
  document.getElementById('react')
);
```

Comment: Thank you for this!  I am going to give this a try tomorrow, but to clarify, the example code you wrote would go in the file where the Exchange blocks are being instantiated?

Comment: You have a React component which creates the JSX (your Exchange components). That's where the code goes. It's a bit late here so I had to code that from memory so there might be something missing. If there's anything you need to know give me a shout in the morning :)

Comment: Hi Andy, I figured my issue, in part, is that I need to actually create an API in my backend java before I can even begin to think about the fetches. I'm looking to use Spring to do this, and hopefully, not too much of my work needs to be recoded.

Comment: That would definitely help. Good luck with the coding. @vynabhnnqwxleicntw.